# How to stream http response in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, streaming

I have tried a sample program to know the concept of streaming in node.js. Below is my code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
//app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.get('/samp', function (req, res) {
    var obj= {"id":"100","name":"xyz"}
    res.setHeader("error-code", 1001);
    res.statusCode = 400;
    obj.pipe(res);
});
app.listen(3000);
```

When I execute this program, I am getting below error.

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'pipe'
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: The error message seems very clear. You create a variable `obj` and try to call a method on it that doesn't exist three lines later. What part is confusing you?

Comment: Did you mean `req.pipe` instead of `obj.pipe`?

Comment: @Chris I am trying to do response streaming. or what is the difference between res.end(obj) and streaming the object

Comment: For a small object like that streaming is overkill.  If you want to try it you probably want to read something like http://www.sitepoint.com/basics-node-js-streams/

Comment: If you want to write all data of `obj` to response stream you can use `res.end(JSON.stringify(obj))`. But this does not support circular objects and functions on it. There is no need for streaming since object you want to write is short.